# Strange behaviour in foreach-loop inside for-loop

Tags: php, post, for-loop, foreach, key

I have encountered a problem I can't get my head around it. I must be missing something, but I can't for get to know what.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text"      name="guest[1][name]"       id="nameG1" /><label for="nameG1"> Namn </label><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[1][veg]"        value="Ja" />Vegetarian (vegan etc. fyll i nedan)<br />
<textarea               name="guest[1][allergies]"  id="allergiesG1"></textarea><label for="allergiesG1">Allergier och andra matpreferenser</label><br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[1][drink]"      value="Öl" />Öl<br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[1][drink]"      value="Cider" />Cider<br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[1][alcfree]"    value="Ja" />Alkoholfritt<br />

<input type="text"      name="guest[2][name]"       id="nameG2" /><label for="nameG2"> Namn </label><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[2][veg]"        value="Ja" />Vegetarian (vegan etc. fyll i nedan)<br />
<textarea               name="guest[2][allergies]"  id="allergiesG2"></textarea><label for="allergiesG2">Allergier och andra matpreferenser</label><br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[2][drink]"      value="Öl" />Öl<br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[2][drink]"      value="Cider" />Cider<br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[2][alcfree]"    value="Ja" />Alkoholfritt<br />

<input type="text"      name="guest[3][name]"       id="nameG3" /><label for="nameG3"> Namn </label><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[3][veg]"        value="Ja" />Vegetarian (vegan etc. fyll i nedan)<br />
<textarea               name="guest[3][allergies]"  id="allergiesG3"></textarea><label for="allergiesG3">Allergier och andra matpreferenser</label><br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[3][drink]"      value="Öl" />Öl<br />
<input type="radio"     name="guest[3][drink]"      value="Cider" />Cider<br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="guest[3][alcfree]"    value="Ja" />Alkoholfritt<br />
```

which is sent via post to this page:

```
for ($j=1; $j<4; $j++) {
    var_dump($_POST['guest'][$j]);

    foreach ($_POST['guest'][$j] as $guest) {                   
        echo key($_POST['guest'][$j]).": ".$guest."<br>";
        next($_POST['guest'][$j]);
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

My problem is that the output from the php code gets messed up in the first loop of the for loop. As you can see in the picture below, the first loop gets messed up, but the other two loops are fine. Please help, I have no clue what is wrong!

I can also say that I have commented out every other vit of code in both files to find whats wrong with this part, so there should be nothing else affecting this.

(http://i44.tinypic.com/2a0gehl.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could be a bit easier to use like this. There is no point in using the `next` and `key` operations when you're already in a foreach() loop that provides that data for you. Since the foreach loop already iterates over each element in the array, calling `next()` manually simply causes PHP to **SKIP** every other element.

```
foreach($_POST['guest'] as $idx => $guest) {
   foreach($guest as $key => $val) {
       echo "$idx: $key => $val<br>";
   }
}
```

which would echo out

```
1: name => foo
1: veg => ...
etc...
2: name => bar
etc...
```